# How to remove background color in OneNote 2013?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I have pasted text from internet, where background was black.

Text was not black on web page, but `OneNote` made it black itself.

So I got black text on black background and can't rid off background.

`Clear formatting` does not help.

`Page background` does not help.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to paste text without the source formatting and one is to right click and select one of the alternative paste options. You can also accomplish this from the paste drop down menu of the Home tab on the Ribbon.

When pasting from Chrome, OneNote gives me the option to paste and:

1. Keep Source Formatting
2. Merge Formatting
3. Paste only text

When you copy some other things (such as a chart from Excel) it gives you more pasting options to keep source data, paste as image, etc.

These are the paste icons shown below the paste button (in their respective order as described above) when you right click:

[image: OneNote paste menu]

Here is the screen shot of the ribbon section:

[image: OneNote paste options on Ribbon]

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

When pasting a table from a website with dark background (for example Microsoft Docs), the background will be black. This can be fixed by going into the "Table Tools > Layout > Shading" and setting the shading to white or no color.

[image: Shading Options]